# How can I automate in Selenium IDE for email activation link?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

In the send invitation process, the user will get a link in his/her inbox. When the user will click on the link, it will ask for a password and confirm the password.

How can I automate it with Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 3):

For some tasks Selenium IDE is not enough. 
Maybe this is a reason to switch to Webdriver?

Please, see also

[Is mail testing with selenium possible?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/is-mail-testing-with-selenium-possible)