# Sending and Verifying emails(all types) with selenium webDriver

Tags: automated-testing

Scenario: After filling the form, mail will be send to some people.

1. How can I validate whether mail(gmail, outlook,etc ..)has been send or not.
2. How can we check whether TO , CC , Subject and content where provided correctly.

Can we automate these functionality with Selenium WebDrivers?

Comment: Possible duplicate check the [link] (http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/is-mail-testing-with-selenium-possible)
Outlook automation is possible not possible with Selenium, as it is desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use Selenium for email testing. Unless you also want to login into a web-based email provider with Selenium. You could send emails to something like [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) and check the mail with their [API](http://docs.mailtrap.apiary.io/#).

I think testing that email are sent is something you need to check in your back-end integration tests. Not in the end2end UI tests.

- Setup a local in memory SMTP server, configure the code to use it
- Trigger the backend to fire the send-email event
- Check the SMTP server got the email, retrieve it and check its contents.

And example can be found here: https://blog.tradeshift.com/email-integration-testing/

Answer (score 0):

Java Implementation for reading outlook and gmail using javaxmail api. Here is the working code snippets:

```
public GmailUtils(String username, String password, String server, EmailFolder 
  emailFolder) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
    props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, "<your email>", "<your password>");

    Folder folder = store.getFolder(emailFolder.getText());
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    System.out.println("Total Messages:" + folder.getMessageCount());
    System.out.println("Unread Messages:" + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());

    messages = folder.getMessages();

    for (Message mail : messages) {
        if (!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {


          System.out.println("***************************************************");
            System.out.println("MESSAGE : \n");             
            System.out.println("Subject: " + mail.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + mail.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("To: " + mail.getAllRecipients()[0]);
            System.out.println("Date: " + mail.getReceivedDate());
            System.out.println("Size: " + mail.getSize());
            System.out.println("Flags: " + mail.getFlags());
            System.out.println("ContentType: " + mail.getContentType());                
            System.out.println("Body: \n" + getEmailBody(mail));
            System.out.println("Has Attachments: " + hasAttachments(mail));

        }
    }
}



    public OutlookEmail(String username, String password, String server, EmailsFolder 
  inbox) throws Exception {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
    props.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");

    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);
    Store store = mailSession.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "<your email>", "<your password>");


    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    System.out.println("Total Message:" + folder.getMessageCount());
    System.out.println("Unread Message:" + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());

    messages = folder.getMessages();

    for (Message mail : messages) {
        if (!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {

            System.out.println("***************************************************");
            System.out.println("MESSAGE : \n");

            System.out.println("Subject: " + mail.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + mail.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("To: " + mail.getAllRecipients()[0]);
            System.out.println("Date: " + mail.getReceivedDate());
            System.out.println("Size: " + mail.getSize());
            System.out.println("Flags: " + mail.getFlags());
            System.out.println("ContentType: " + mail.getContentType());
            System.out.println("Body: \n" + getEmailBody(mail));
            System.out.println("Has Attachments: " + hasAttachments(mail));

        }
    }
}

public boolean hasAttachments(Message email) throws Exception {

    // suppose 'message' is an object of type Message
    String contentType = email.getContentType();
    System.out.println(contentType);

    if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("multipart/mixed")) {
        // this message must contain attachment
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) email.getContent();

        for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                System.out.println("Attached filename is:" + part.getFileName());

                MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) part;
                String fileName = mimeBodyPart.getFileName();

                String destFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Resources\\";

                File fileToSave = new File(fileName);
                mimeBodyPart.saveFile(destFilePath + fileToSave);

                // download the pdf file in the resource folder to be read by PDFUTIL api.

                PDFUtil pdfUtil = new PDFUtil();
                String pdfContent = pdfUtil.getText(destFilePath + fileToSave);

                System.out.println("******---------------********");
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("Started reading the pdfContent of the attachment:==");


                System.out.println(pdfContent);

                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("******---------------********");

                Path fileToDeletePath = Paths.get(destFilePath + fileToSave);
                Files.delete(fileToDeletePath);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public String getEmailBody(Message email) throws IOException, MessagingException {

    String line, emailContentEncoded;
    StringBuffer bufferEmailContentEncoded = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(email.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        bufferEmailContentEncoded.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println("**************************************************");

    System.out.println(bufferEmailContentEncoded);

    System.out.println("**************************************************");

    emailContentEncoded = bufferEmailContentEncoded.toString();

    if (email.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains("multipart/related")) {

        emailContentEncoded = emailContentEncoded.substring(emailContentEncoded.indexOf("base64") + 6);
        emailContentEncoded = emailContentEncoded.substring(0, emailContentEncoded.indexOf("Content-Type") - 1);

        System.out.println(emailContentEncoded);

        String emailContentDecoded = new String(new Base64().decode(emailContentEncoded.toString().getBytes()));
        return emailContentDecoded;
    }

    return emailContentEncoded;

}
```